# Loop that references different sheet names each iteration

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following loop to create multiple tabs in Excel 2016 based on a list of PO#'s. ( see code below)

```
Sub CreateSheetsFromAList()

    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim dic As Object, c As Range
    Dim k As Variant, tmp As String

    Set dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set MyRange = Sheets("Instructions").Range("h6")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))
    Sheets("Template").Visible = True

    For Each c In MyRange
        tmp = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(tmp) > 0 Then dic(tmp) = dic(tmp) + 1


    Next c

    For Each k In dic.keys
        If Not WorksheetExists(k) Then
          Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
          ActiveSheet.Name = k
        End If
    Next k

    End Sub

Public Function WorksheetExists(ByVal WorksheetName As String) As Boolean
On Error Resume Next
  WorksheetExists = (Sheets(WorksheetName).Name <> "")
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

I also need to populate each newly created tab with info from another workbook (EDI PO Consolidated - 2018.xlsx) 
(see code below)

```
Sub BandB2()
' BandB2 Macro
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+b
'
    Application.Goto Reference:="R20C10"
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("EDI PO Consolidated - 2018.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$X$2628").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
        "34535453"
    Application.Goto Reference:="R1C9"
    Range("I2058").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Book and Bill form - template.xlsm").Activate
    Range("J26").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Windows("EDI PO Consolidated - 2018.xlsx").Activate
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=4
    Application.Goto Reference:="R1C17"
    Range("Q2058").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Book and Bill form - template.xlsm").Activate
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6
    Range("C33").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Windows("EDI PO Consolidated - 2018.xlsx").Activate
    Application.Goto Reference:="R1C14"
    Range("N2058").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Book and Bill form - template.xlsm").Activate
    Range("D33").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Windows("EDI PO Consolidated - 2018.xlsx").Activate
    Application.Goto Reference:="R1C18"
    Range("R2058:T2058").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Book and Bill form - template.xlsm").Activate
    Range("E33").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

I have 2 questions:

1) i cannot make the sheet reference change for each tab; it always picks the 
1st po# "34535453"

2) Can you help me combine these into 1 macro.

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Can you provide examples of your workbook and what it should look like? Also (and I seem to type this pretty much every day), when you work with objects, you don't need to select sheets or workbooks.. you already have the object, just use it to reference what you need to.. just a tip

Comment: Zac - i am new to stack can you tell me how to post attachments of the files

Comment: here is t he link to my drop box

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/58t4sh0ijps650g/edi%20po%20consol%20-2018%20-%20sample.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/deni3kkfr0sydqd/Book%20and%20Bill%20form%20-%20template%20-%20sample.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/c1kfs8rtwf7231q/Book%20and%20Bill%20form%20-%20template%20-%20sample%20before.xlsm?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cleaner way to create those tabs.

Name cell H6 on the Instructions tab "PO_Start" or some other appropriate name. That way if you can insert rows or columns on the tab without possibly having to change the reference to H6 in your code.

```
Sub Create_Sheets()

Dim PO_list, PO As Range

Set PO_list = Range(Sheets("Instructions").Range("PO_Start"), Sheets("Instructions").Range("PO_Start").End(xlDown))
Sheets("Template").Visible = True

For Each PO In PO_list
    If Not WorksheetExists(PO) Then
          Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
          ActiveSheet.Name = PO
    End If
Next PO

End Sub
```

1) To loop through your tabs, if you know that your PO tabs will always start on tab 3, you can loop through the sheets like this (including variable declarations):

```
Sub B_and_B()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

For i = 3 To Sheets.Count
    Set ws = Sheets(i)
    '... rest of code here
Next i

End Sub
```

Otherwise if down the road you anticipate adding other sheets besides "Instructions" and "Template" to your Book and Bill file, you could loop through all sheets, error checking to see if you can convert the sheet name to a "long" variable type with `Clng()`. Probably more than what's needed for your current project.

Another tip: 
Avoid using hard-coded cell addresses ("N2058") in your code. If you filter on purchase orders in the Consolidated book and then pull in certain data elements, you'll need to find the row the Purchase Order is in (2058 in this case).

2) To combine these into one macro, you can create a Main subroutine, calling each step separately:

```
Sub Main()

Call Create_Sheets
Call B_and_B

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! i will try this in the am. here is the sample data from edi po consol

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/58t4sh0ijps650g/edi%20po%20consol%20-2018%20-%20sample.xlsx?dl=0